# How to fix error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'drawContours'

Tags: opencv, contour

Draw Contours error
I am trying to draw contour for the objects in the image

```
(_, contours) = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# draw contours over original image
length = len(contours)
for c in range(length):
    cv2.drawContours(img,contours,c,(255,0,0),3)

cv2.namedWindow("output", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("output", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I expect the all the contours to be drawn but the actual result that i get is 
error:

> (-215:Assertion failed) npoints > 0 in function 'drawContours'

Comment: Any chance to share the complete code to have a working example? Post software versions, and also your input image and output image (erroneous version if possible) and original traceback. Python?

Answer (score 2):

Contours should be numpy array.
Change your code to:

```
for c in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[c], 0, (255,0,0),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have contours, hierarchy backwards. See OpenCv docs on [findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0)

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary,2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```